# Update product table without past recorded purchases?

Tags: sql, database

How to update a product table without affecting previous order details tables, if the product has a new value it does not modify the total purchase value of previous order details lists?

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include both sample table data _and_ the expected result (as properly formatted text, no pictures.) Also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Add a version number column to your product table and make ProdNo + Version the PK. Update any FKs referencing Product to use this new PK. Alternatively, add the price at the time the order is created to the ProductInOrder table and use that rather than the Price on the Product table

Comment: If you have customers with discount arrangements  (& each of these can different!) , or you have a promotion or sale, then having just one value for price will be a real problem.

Comment: @jarlh It's a software engineering question, there is no actual query attempt because first I need to define modeling, so it's independent of particular dbms.